# Can I control handstontables autocomplete edtors initial value?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

With Handsontable, I use autocomplete columns to let users choose from a list of pre defined names. But when the user selects a name I don't actually store that name on my data object, I store an id connected to the name. The id is also what is available on the data when the table is loaded initially.

This means that I need a function to go from id to name and vice versa which I have. I use the id to name function in my renderer and I use the name to id function in `beforeChange`, so that the output contains the id.

**Here is my problem:**

If I select a cell with a name rendered and I press enter, I now see the id instead of the name. Is there some way I can change the behavior of the editor so that the name is shown instead of the id?

Everything else seems to work. If I for instance select a cell and start typing, it now contains what I typed and the autocomplete works as expected. I would like to have the same behavior when pressing enter on a cell.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a solution where I do the translation on all the data when it is loaded. When I then extract data from the sheet I translate it back.

I encountered a similar problem with the date editor where I wanted to go back and forth between the user date format and our normalized date format. Handsons editors are not that easy to work with and especially the date editor receives dates in different formats on `setValue`.

The solution feels a bit hacky but at the same time there will only be on these two occasions when data is transformed which makes it less plausible that there will be any errors compared to if I were to transform on render, data entry, validation etc. With this solution I know that as long as we are in the sheet, the data is what the user sees.